# Read_external_storage permission is not working even i have declared in manifest,not running in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, permissions, storage

[I have declared permission of read external storage in manifest but it is not getting in java file as mentioned in the pic, it shows red colour READ_EXTERNAL_SOTRAGE...i don't know why it is showing red in color][1]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To encourage other users to help you with your issue, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please do *not* provide the source code as an image/photo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide code as text not as an image

Answer (score 0):

Write android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, it will work.

or instead import android.Manifest at the top.

Comment: Thnks meet...could tell me pls, when i am taking pic from gallery it shows blur,not taking pic from gallery..i have written correct code but still not access gallery image..and i have given permission in manifest and inside mobile both....what should i do?

Comment: Please add relevant code which is not working in the question so that I can help you with it.

Also if my answer helped you, please up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Erase `manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

now write half spelling of manifest like , just "Mani" , then 2-3 Manifest options will be shown in autocomplete So choose the one which says "Manifest android" not the one which says "Manifest "

now just write `.permission` and  now it will suggest u name of android permissions and select or type `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Bro I know the Exact answer can be removed . 

Please just stick to the answer for the community to read it easily.